# How do i use an SQL query to determine TFS Area name and build path including file name for installers

Tags: sql-server, tfs

I am trying to automate the release process associated with installers that have been created on my build server.  To do this I was hoping to be able to use an SQL query to get the drop path of the installer including the file name.

In TFS when I go to "Build" and select "Artifacts" I can then use the "Explore" link to get the root path for the build.  The subsequent folders "Installer\Disk" path is part of the configuration.  However, the actual setup file is composed of the  + " setup.exe".  Since there are multiple projects in our TFS I was hoping to use a query to find all builds that have a build quality set to "Release" and dynamically find the installer on disk.

Generally our installer names are made up of the root area path name with all text removed.  I can't figure out how to connect the build to the root area path in SQL.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Generally, Accessing the information from Database directly is not recommended since it is in a high risk. I would recommend you to use [TFS API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.build.client.ibuildserver(v=vs.120).aspx) to do this.

The drop location of the build is stored in TFS Collection Database\tbl_Build table and the quality information is stored in tbl_BuildQuality table. Join these two tables to query the information you want.

Comment: Thanks Eddie.  Do you have any code samples that would be helpful if I went the API route.  I don't yet have any experience with the TFS API.  Using the tbl_Build table and the tbl_BuildQuality tables don't provide me with the actual name of the setup.exe file.  I have to append "Installer\Disk1" but there is no text in these tables which tells me the actual installer project name.